# 1INCH Version error

Tags: solidity, remix, exchanges, compiler, import

I got error importing and using 1INCH. The problem is in the versions. In **IOneSplit.sol** version is 0.5.0 (`pragma solidity ^0.5.0`). And IOneSplit imports **IERC20** which is in 0.8.0 (`pragma solidity ^0.8.0`). I'm using RemixIDE. Is the error from my side? How can I fix it?

IERC20: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol

IOneSplit: https://github.com/1inch/1inchProtocol/blob/master/contracts/IOneSplit.sol

---

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use OpenZeppelin contracts' version 2.5, it was the latest to support solc 0.5.x: [IERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol).

Comment: Thank you @Ismael. Are you sure I won't get errors from SafeMath etc.?

Comment: @RafayelKh You have two options either downgrade OpenZeppelin to v2.5 use solc v0.5  or migrate to IOneSplit to use solc v0.8.